# Cannot set canvas width and change font at the same time?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/sLk72mud/

Inn the jsfiddle, the call to measureText that sets the canvas width:

```
tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
```

overwrites the font size:

```
tCtx.font = "25px serif"
```

If I remove the call to measureText, then the canvas uses the font size I expect. Unfortunately I then have to guess on how wide to make my canvas. Why is this and is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the canvas dimensions also resets the context. You'll need to set the font again (and any other non-default settings) after the resize.

```js
   tCtx.font = 'bold 24px serif';
   tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
   tCtx.font = 'bold 24px serif';
   tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
```

Saved states (via [`.save()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save)/[`.restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore)) are also lost on a resize. If you expect to have a number of changes to the canvas state, you may want to break these out into your own `.save()`/`.restore()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

just move the tCtx.font statement to be directly before fillText statement

```
   tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
   tCtx.font = 'bold 24px serif';
   tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
```

Comment: But then `.measureText()` is using an old or default font setting.

Comment: ya you need to define it twice one before resizing and one after resizing